# Dynamic TaskGroups vs Dynamic DAGs

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

Suppose I have a process with tasks:

`T1 >> T2 >> T3`

The process needs to be run for a set of ids [1,2,3]:

```
process_run_with_id1

process_run_with_id2

process_run_with_id3
```

I can either create a single DAG with multiple TaskGroups, where each TaskGroup represents the set of tasks to be run for the id:

`DAG = > TG_for_1, TG_for_2, TG_for_3`

Or multiple DAGs

```
DAG_for_1 = t1 >> t2 >> t3

DAG_for_2 = t1 >> t2 >> t3  

DAG_for_3 = t1 >> t2 >> t3
```

Other than visually being different, what are the differences between the two approaches (and whether I'm creating the DAGs dynamically by having a file creating DAGs or having multiple DAG files)?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the same result by splitting tasks across DAG or joining them to a single DAG but this is more of how you define result.
You can also write a whole software in a single file but is it smart to place everything in the same file? probably not.

There are a few rules which can help you distinguish between adding a task group of tasks vs creating a separated DAG.

Points in favor of adding the tasks with Task Group to the current DAG:

1. The tasks are a subunit of the DAG.
2. The tasks in the group are never to be executed as a stand alone. Execution is always as part of the DAG itself.
3. The tasks share similar/close business logic with the DAG so it make sense to find these tasks within the specific DAG.

Points in favor of separating the tasks from current DAG to another DAG:

1. Tasks may need to run separately from the current DAG.
2. Tasks represent a separate business unit which may be independent or be executed after the current DAG.
3. Code change within the tasks will not require any additional change to the current DAG.

Overall, I think the most important one to understand is that while tasks groups are just a pretty UI representation. This means that if for any reason `TG_for_1` will take longer to be executed, it may cause delay in scheduling new DAG runs which means it will effect not only the tasks in `TG_for_1` but also the tasks of the following run of `TG_for_2` & `TG_for_3` which will be delayed. Thus you want to "bind" the tasks into the same DAG only if it make sense that they will run together and "suffer" together if there are issues.