# Airflow: Should one prefer branching or seperate dags or branching within tasks?

Tags: python, airflow

Which of the following is better and why?

1 dag with branching

```
               -> A1 -> A2 -> ...
              /
step1 -> step2 -> B1 -> B2 -> ...
              \ 
               -> C1 -> C2 -> ...
```

or 3 separate dags?

```
step1 -> step2 -> A1 -> A2 -> 

step1 -> step2 -> B1 -> B2 -> 

step1 -> step2 -> C1 -> C2 ->
```

or 1 dag with tasks handling branching logic based on xcom value from previous task

```
step1 -> step2 -> (A1 | B1 | C1) -> (A2 | B2 | C2) ->
```

Comment: It will mostly depend on your use case. Is there a reason they should no be in the same DAG?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/68399242/14624409 while it's on tasks group vs seperate dags this still applies to your dilemma.